# Properly installing frameworks in OSX & linking them to Eclipse IDE project

Tags: eclipse, macos, frameworks, linker, eclipse-cdt

I'm new to OSX and i'm getting used to the way frameworks work.

In c++ projects, when i want to link a preinstalled framework, for example OpenGL.framework, i just type "-framework OpenGL" and i'm good to go.

On the other side, when i copy a new framework into for example /Library/Frameworks, and i go "-framework MyFramework", the framework is not linked properly. Eclipse doesn't find the file. I also add "-F/Library/Frameworks" but still it doesn't find it.

Do i have to do something else than copying the framework to the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't rebooted since installing the framework, you might have to update the shared library cache manually:

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache
```

The other option is to reboot. To make completely sure that the frameworks will be rescanned, you can touch the directory containing them first:

```
sudo touch /Library/Frameworks
sudo reboot
```

If this does not work, it is likely that the framework you installed is not properly formed. The directory structure, plist file, etc, need to follow a set of rules to form a framework.

Comment: Well... sad to say i just needed a reboot. Updating the shared library cache also worked. Anyway i have to include the headers myself and normally just the "-framework MyFramework" line is needed for that. Why can that be?